# Displaying query results in a different place from the query

Tags: php

Basically I'v got a HTML Form that links to a php file in a different location for it's action, Currently I'm using the form to update the users profiles and then send them back to the editprofile.php. Basically at the top of editprofile.php if they've submitted the query I want to display the result of either "Profile Updated" or "Failed to Update", issue is I can't workout how to display query results when the query is in a different file.

I tried to do this;

```
<?php
   if(!$query)
   {
     echo '<div class="editfail">Profile failed to update!</div>';
   } 
   else 
   {
     echo '<div class="editsuccess">Profile successfully updated!</div>';
   }
?>
```

Except the issue with this is that the query hasn't been run on this page, it was run from another page and then redirected back to the editprofile page using a header, so how can I display the same results as above when the query is being executed from another location?

Comment: If you're using GET or POST, usually the $_GET and $_POST arrays are still accessible if you've used require or include to link to another PHP file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send parameter when you are redirecting back the file.

example

if(mysql_query($update_query))
   {

```
     header('location:editprofile.php?msg="success to save"');

}
else
{
    header('location:editprofile.php?msg="failed to save"');
}
```

Or even you can send flag also

```
if(mysql_query($update_query))
{
 header('location:editprofile.php?flag=0');
}else
{

header('location:editprofile.php?flag=1');
}
```

And check the value of flag in your editprofile.php file to display proper message.

Comment: How/where can I find more information on flags, I'v not learnt them nor have I used them before and I'm unable to find information on them via the php.net site.

Comment: Flag is here is your own created one. It is like a value by which you can take decision what to do.

Comment: so if I were to do `header('location:editprofile.php?flag=1');` What would be the best way to define what outputs on the other page? Sorry Don't believe I'v ever done this before.

Comment: After reading what you wrote a few times it occurred to me how I would use these, I have opted to give you the correct answer as it was the solution I chose to use.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't mess around with the headers fxn unless you need to - depending on output_buffer settings etc they can be a pain:

You can do what you want - all in 1 single page:

So something like this  -As a matter of common convention, and to a degree security, you should post the form to itself - you can integrate whatever else from the other page into the pass/fail profile logic block:

```
  <?php
   $query = htmlentities($_POST['profiletext']); #sanitize avec tu code du jour

   if(!$query || $query != 'someacceptablevalue))
   {
     #If it's not posted, or its not a good value, tell them it failed
     # and redisplay the form to try again

     $query_msg = '<div class="editfail">Profile failed to update!</div>';
     $profile_form = "<div_class='profile_rest_of_page stuff'>
           <form action='#' method='post'>
             <input type='text' id='profiletext' name='profiletext/>
           </form>
         </div>";
   } 
   else 
   {
     # They did it - Success, and link to next step
     $query_msg = '<div class="editsuccess">Profile successfully updated!</div>';
     $profile_form = 'No form needed - you did it';
   }

   #One block below handles all in 1 page with above logic:

   echo "<body>
          <div class='profile_message_container'>
             $query_msg
          </div>
         <div_class='profile_rest_of_page stuff'>
             $profile_redo<br/> You did it <a href='next'>next</a>
         </div>
        </body>
        ";       
  ?>
```

Comment: The issue with this is I'v already got over 800 lines of code within the page, I'm a little uneasy adding another 170 odd lines of code in as I'm running out of ways to keep everything organised and easily accessible, I'v tried to keep everything in separate files and include/use them where needed rather then do everything in one page. If I do go with this method I'll be doing it in a separate file and requiring it. I'm unsure which method I'll use right now, still trying to find more information on the header flag function.

Comment: In that case you'll get into ob_flush etc issues if there is any sort of output in those potentially. Sounds like you need some sort of MVC framework - PITA - but worth the horrid trouble to get started down the road.

Comment: Sounds like it'd be way to far out of my knowledge's reach, I learnt PHP back when I was 12 and I haven't used it for several years so i'm sort of recapping and remembering stuff as I go along, I may look into the MVC Framework but I dare say it'll be too complicated for me to code right now. At the moment I'm just sort of coding what I need as I go along and sort of merging it into my already coded scripts, kind of like an awful CMS I guess you could say.

Comment: I'v opted to use flags, There was nothing wrong with your answer infact it was most informative and I'll likely look into the methods you've stated down the path but at the current time it wasn't for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways:

1. Send the query results in the link like a GET which could be tampered with
2. Process the form in the same page that has your form as follows

> ```
> if(isset($_POST['some_name'])) {
>     // Process form
> } else {
>    // Display form
> }
> ```